# WPF data grid for financial style reporting?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, financial, subtotal

I'm looking for a decent WPF data grid or solution involving one to represent financial data.

I've looked at many - the WPF one, XCeed, Ingragistics, DevExpress, etc.... but none of them seem to offer the simple requirement I have:

I want to be able to display group subtotals in their columns in the group row, e.g.

```
GROUP 1           xxxx.xx   
  GROUP 2         xxxx.xx
    ROW 1           xx.xx
    ROW 2           xx.xx
```

Does anyone know of a grid that does this, or a nice supporting collection that implements aggregate functions (group totals would need to be used in individual line items) so that existing grids with a bit of XAML styling would work?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ViBlend DataGrid](http://www.viblend.com/products/net/wpf/controls/data-grid.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, this looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a PivotGrid?  If so, take also a look at the [DXPivotGrid for WPF](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Pivot_Grid/)