# WPF datagrid grouping

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm grouping my grid like this:

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(_ActionCollection);
            collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("InvoiceNumber"));
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Now I want to get the sum of the items which are grouped.

For example:

If grouped ivnoice number 231 and 245 contain both 3 rows, how can I get the sum for the example id?

Comment: Why not create a query and use LINQ grouping operators?

Answer (score 1):

The base **.NET DataGrid** is just that - low level.  Therefore, operations like this will require not only aggregate queries like the one metioned but also extensive UX effort.

Please refer to this post -- [WPF data grid for financial style reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845842/wpf-data-grid-for-financial-style-reporting) -- as it may be a better approach.